# Replacement for adding certificate in .net6 app

Tags: azure, .net-6.0, azure-keyvault, client-certificates, appsettings

I am struggling with replacing my existing add certificate code when upgrading from .net 4.8 to .net 6

Here is the set up post upgrade:

Program.cs

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        LoadConfiguration(builder);

        var startup = new MyWebApp.Startup(builder.Configuration);
        startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

        WebApplication app = builder.Build();        
        await app.RunAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //register
            RegisterServices(services);
            //register
        }

void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // DbContext       

        // Other project registrations
        //Repo etc
        services.RegisterClients(Configuration);
    }
```

Client CS Project

```
//Extension
public static class DIExtension
    {        
        // Registers the clients to the given builder        
        public static void RegisterClients(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            //services.AddHttpClient

            services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>("MPC", c =>
            {
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = true;
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetConnectionString("Url"));
            }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
                new HttpClientHandler().AddClientCertificate(configuration.GetValue<string>("MyCertificates:MyThumbprint")));
        }
    }
```

HttpHandlerExt

```
public static HttpClientHandler AddClientCertificate(this HttpClientHandler handler, string thumbPrint)
    {
        handler = handler ?? new HttpClientHandler();

        var cert = GetMyCertificate(thumbPrint);

        if (cert == null)
        {
            return handler;
        }

        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        return handler;
    }

    private static X509Certificate2 GetMyCertificate(string thumbPrint)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbPrint, false);
            if (col == null || col.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new CertificateException($"Certificate was not found for thumbprint {thumbPrint}");
            }
            return col[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
    }
```

```
//appsettings

"MyCertificates": {
    "MyThumbprint": "thumprintvalue"
  },
```

The thumprints are available in Certificates of KV. I do not want the thumprint value to be available directly in appsetting.
Please let me know if any additional information is required, I have tried to give as much information and code as possible from my end.

Comment: Hello Community, Please let me know if I am missing any infromation in my question

Comment: I'm not clear what question you are asking. Can you describe what you are trying to do besides replacing your .NET Framework code with .NET 6 (which, BTW, should just work apart from some app settings API changes - nothing to do with the Key Vault SDK).

Comment: Thank you for your question. I am looking for a way to avoid having thumbprint in my appsettings exposed. Above I have shown how it is being used at the moment to try and have minimum disruption.

Comment: How is the app supposed to know what certificate to use? Thumbprints are also public and meant to be shared. It's common to list a key by it's thumbprint in app config. De facto, even.

Comment: Hello Heath.. Sorry for the delay, I have not been keeping well. I mean I do not want the thumbprint value in the app setting, I want a way to have it resolved in runtime rather than it having hardcoded value assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the Thumbprint from the Azure Key Vault Certificate by using Azure Key Vault SDK.

- We just need to pass the Key Vault URI.

Install the `Azure.Identity` and `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets` NuGet Packages

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.5.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

- First, we will retrieve the Thumbprint in the bytes format, later convert it using `X509Certificate2`

***My `Startup.cs` file:***

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

internal class Startup
{
    private ConfigurationManager configuration;

    public Startup(ConfigurationManager configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        RegisterServices(services);
    }

    void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {       
        string Thumbprint = GetCertificateThumbprint();
    }

    static string GetCertificateThumbprint()
    {
        var KVCred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        var KVURI = "https://harshukv4july.vault.azure.net/";

        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(KVURI), KVCred);

        var CertName = "Certificare4July";
        var secret = client.GetSecret(CertName);

        byte[] ThumbPrintinBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value.Value);

        var KVCertificate = new X509Certificate2(ThumbPrintinBytes);
        var CertThumbPrint = KVCertificate.Thumbprint;
        Console.WriteLine($"Thumbprint from Azure Certificate  : { CertThumbPrint }");

        return CertThumbPrint;
    }
}
```

***OutPut:***

[image]

[image]

Verify the value in `Key Vault Certificate`:

[image]